# Trying to set a image to a Image Control in Dispatcher makes a error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Here is some of my codes:

```
var dispatcher = this.Dispatcher;
new Task(new Action(delegate
{
   BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
   //...code for loading image
   Action updateImage = () => { this.picCover.Source = bi; };
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateImage);
})).Start();
```

`picCover` is a image widget.
Here `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateImage);` I got a `System.InvalidOperationException`: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
I also tried to replace `this.Dispatcher` to `picCover.Dispatcher`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what the error is but if I'm not wrong it's

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

If that's the case it's because `BitmapImage` itself is a `DispatcherObject` so it matters on which thread you've created it and on which thread you want to use it. You need to [`Freeze`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx) bitmap image as it was created on different thread

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
//...code for loading image

bi.Freeze();

Action updateImage = () => { this.picCover.Source = bi; };
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateImage);
```

Comment: Thank you. But the compiler showed that "This Freezable cannot be frozen." Then I handled `Download Completed` event but it never be called.

Comment: The answer is in house you load your bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make it this way:

```
async void Test()
{
  var dispatcher = this.Dispatcher;
  await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    //...code for loading image

    this.picCover.Source = bi;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
var dispatcher = this.Dispatcher;
new Task(new Action(delegate
{

    Action updateImage = () => {

        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/c6/f2/7b/c6f27bf410ff72b91a7947ef5ee94f3d.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
        bi.EndInit();

        this.picCover.Source = bi; 

    };
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateImage);
})).Start();
```

Comment: I tried. But the UI did not respond when loading the image

Comment: Maybe you have a high speed network. Finally I used `WebClient` for downloading images .And putting returned bytes into a `MemoryStream`,  replacing `new Uri(...)` with the `Stream` worked it out.

Comment: @Zhangzijing Which one worked ? Your approach or mine ? If mine worked, plz mark it as answer with an upvote.

Comment: If you had loaded the image from stream directly, your way would work.